# get_the_archive_title hook unwanted changes!

Tags: filters, hooks, title, wp-title

I use get_the_archive_title hook to add a link to my blog tags and categories archives pages.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_the_archive_title/

I just get the title and filter it to include it into an  title  like this:
[image]

but it also changes the browser tab title =(
 [image]

How can I avoid this??
Thank you!

Comment: Quick & Dirty: use [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/function.debug-backtrace.php) to see who's calling that filter?

Comment: yup, called by blog-header.php, any option to return $content when called from there so I don't filter it?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to see where it was called from:

```
add_filter("get_the_archive_title", function($val) {
     $backtrace = debug_backtrace();
     foreach($backtrace as $level) {
         if(array_key_exists("file", $level) && preg_match("!that-file\.php$!",  $level["file"]) && array_key_exists("function", $level) && $level["function"] == "get_the_archive_title" ) {
             return "works: $val";
         }
     }
     return "test: $val";
 }, 10, 1);
```

You'll have to adapt the regexp ("that-file.php") to your needs, and potentially check for another function if it's not done with `get_the_archive_title()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [document title filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/document_title/) to [strip out HTML tags](https://www.php.net/strip_tags) from the `<title>` tag. However, note that there is already a default WordPress filter that is [escaping HTML from the document title](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/7208116a8c2de1b85ae17af4224b18923c1759cb/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L157), so you want to insert your filter before it.

Here is one way to do it:

```php
// Temporarily remove WordPress esc_html filter
remove_filter('document_title', 'esc_html');
// Add our own filter to strip out HTML tags
add_filter('document_title', 'strip_tags');
// Put back the esc_html filter so that it will be called after strip_tags
add_filter('document_title', 'esc_html');
```